# Passing props to an axios query

Tags: reactjs, axios

My intention is to get the weather data for the selected country, passing selectedCountry.capital to the query, so it is displayed the weather from current country capital when the data of a country is displayed.

```
useEffect(() => {

  axios
    .get(
      `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=b51dfd70b0b2ccf136a0d7352876661c&query=${selectedCountry.capital}`
    )
    .then(res =>{
      console.log(res.data)
      console.log("capital"+selectedCountry.capital)
      setWeather(res.data.current)
    } )

}, [])
```

First problem: I am not passing selectedCountry.capital to the query, since     console.log("capital"+selectedCountry.capital) returns undefined.

If I hardcode the query, I get a weather response.

```
useEffect(() => {

  axios
    .get(
      `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=b51dfd70b0b2ccf136a0d7352876661c&query=New York`
    )
    .then(res =>{
      console.log(res.data)
      console.log("capital"+selectedCountry.capital)
      setWeather(res.data.current)
    } )

}, [])
```

How do I pass selectedCountry.capital to the weather query?

Full code:
[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-wind-9on0z?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
//setCountries is a function for setting the country's state
const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
//Filter
const [searchFilter, setSearchFilter] = useState('')

//Update state with button
const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState('')

const [weather, setWeather] = useState('')
  
const hook = () => {
    console.log('effect')
    axios
      .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then(response => {
        console.log('promise fulfilled')
        setCountries(response.data)
        
      })
  }

  useEffect(hook,[])
/*   by default the effect is always run after the component has been rendered. In our case, however, we only want to execute the effect along with the first render.
  The second parameter of useEffect is used to specify how often the effect is run. If the second parameter is an empty array [], then the effect is only run along with the first render of the component. */

  console.log('render', countries.length, 'countries')
  console.log(countries)

/* weather */
useEffect(() => {

  axios
    .get(
      `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=b51dfd70b0b2ccf136a0d7352876661c&query=New York`
    )
    .then(res =>{
      console.log(res.data)
      console.log("capital"+selectedCountry.capital)
      setWeather(res.data.current)
    } )

}, [])



  //When button es clicked the state is set, and the state variable is used

  const renderCountryDetails = () => {
    return (
      selectedCountry && (
        <p key={selectedCountry.alpha2Code}>
       <p>   Capital: {selectedCountry.capital}.</p>
       <p>  Population:{" "}
          {selectedCountry.population}</p> 

          <p>
            <img src={selectedCountry.flag} style={{ width: '200px'}}/>
</p> 
        
<h3>Languages</h3>
<p>      {selectedCountry.languages.map(language => <li key={language.name}>{language.name}</li>)}



</p>



</p>


      )
    );
  };



const filteredCountries =
searchFilter.length === 1
? countries
: countries.filter(
(country) => country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter.toLowerCase()) > -1
)

//showCountries returns either a message or else the contents of filteredcountries array
const showCountries = () => {


if (filteredCountries.length > 10) {
return 'Too many matches, keep on typing'
}


if (filteredCountries.length > 0 
    && filteredCountries.length<10 
    && filteredCountries.length>1 ) 
    {
      return (
        <div>
          {filteredCountries.map((country) => (
            <p key={country.alpha2Code}>
              {country.name}
              {
                //Update stste when button is clicked, passing country as a prop to the state
                //onClick state is updated, causing the page to refresh and executing renderCountryDetails
                //that uses the set state (the country) to render the info.
                <button onClick={
                  () => setSelectedCountry(country)}>
                  show
                </button>
              }
            </p>
          ))}
          <div>{renderCountryDetails()}</div>
          <div>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    

    if (filteredCountries.length === 1) {
      return filteredCountries.map((country) =>

      
  <p key={country.alpha2Code}>
    <p>Capital: {country.capital}.
    <p> Population: {country.population} </p> 
    <h3>languages</h3>
                {country.languages.map(language => <li key={language.name}>{language.name}</li>)}

    <p><img src={country.flag} style={{ width: '200px'}}/>
    </p> 
    
    </p>
    </p>

  )
      }
    } 
     


const searchHandler = (e) => {
  //setSelectedCountry state is set to empty
  setSelectedCountry("");
setSearchFilter(e.target.value)
}

  return (
<div>

<div>
<h1>Countries</h1>
</div>
<div>
Type to find countries: 
<input onChange={searchHandler} />
<div>
{showCountries()}
</div>
</div>

</div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are miss understand about useEffect. If you use `useEffect(()=> {}, [])`, it will be re-render the first time of lifecycle component.

I just quick fix to show your code like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bePhn.png) with [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-elion-h07in?file=/src/App.js)

If you put the `selectCity` state in `useEffect(()=>{}, [selectCity]`, the component will be re-render when `selectCity` changes.

Hope this work for you.

Comment: Hello. by doing as you say [selectedCountry.capital])  I can log the capital. But it is some weird way to do it.
And I can't display the weather data, since It will pass the selectedCountry.capital only after I select the country. 
There should be another way.

Comment: oh. I got your problem. Ypu can set the value of `selectedContry.capital` only onetime by some action, such as "OK" button click then set value `capital'.

Comment: you also can check in useEffect function  `if (!selectedContry.capital) return;`. That will only show country one time after having valid value.